# ADT List adding elemnts with same rank C

Tags: c

Trying to understand a question that is what are the contents of L after adding the elemnts on it,
L being an ADT List in C.
Assume the ADT List is alredy implemented.

```
//code
int main() {
 PtList L = listCreate();
 listAdd(L, 0, 'a');
 listAdd(L, 2, 'b');
 listAdd(L, 1, 'c');
 listAdd(L, 1, 'd');
 listAdd(L, 3, 'e');
 listAdd(L, 2, 'f');
 listAdd(L, 3, 'f');
 listDestroy(&L);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tought there couldn't be 2 elements in a rank so I awsered L = a,d,f,f
However the solution is L = a, d, f, f, c, e
Which makes no sense. If it can have the same element where's the b?

Thanks,

Comment: can you include the function listAdd?

Comment: The question I am provided with is this one, but the function is listAdd(PtList list, int rank, ListElem elem);

Comment: "ADT list" could mean anything. So this kind of comes across as "explain my code to me".

Comment: This is a question from a questionary I awsered wrong and can't find anywhere the explanation to the right awser. This is all the context I get to awser it. However if you are correct that explains why I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: ADT just means Abstract Data Type, a generic, older term that pre-dates OOP, roughly equivalent to _class_. So your list could be a single-linked list, double-linked list, queue, priority queue, set, etc etc...

Comment: Does the question on the test describe what `listAdd` does with the rank?

Comment: If the rank is the position on the list where the element is to be inserted, perhaps `listAdd(L, 2, 'b');` is rejected because only positions 0 and 1 are valid at that point due to the list being one element long.

Comment: @Ian  nope this is all the entire question. Nothing else is provided.

Comment: Also I think your second comment is right! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No information has been provided about what `listAdd()` does with the specified rank. That should have been provided in the original question from the exam.  Since this information was apparently not provided (according to OP), the exam question is badly constructed.

Since the question on the exam was asking what the contents of the list are after:

```
 PtList L = listCreate();
 listAdd(L, 0, 'a');
 listAdd(L, 2, 'b');
 listAdd(L, 1, 'c');
 listAdd(L, 1, 'd');
 listAdd(L, 3, 'e');
 listAdd(L, 2, 'f');
 listAdd(L, 3, 'f');
```

and the "correct" solution is:

> a, d, f, f, c, e

the behaviour of `listAdd` can be reverse engineered to use the following rules:

1. The specified "rank" is the position on the list to insert the new element, counting from 0.
2. If the "rank" of the new element is greater than the current length of the list or less than zero, do nothing.
3. Otherwise, create the new element with the specified "value" and insert it at position "rank" in the list. This will effectively increase the rank of any original elements at position "rank" or greater up by one.

The following shows the contents of the list at each step, with newly added elements marked with `*`:

```
PtList L = listCreate();  // []
listAdd(L, 0, 'a');       // [*a]
listAdd(L, 2, 'b');       // [ a]  (no element inserted due to invalid position)
listAdd(L, 1, 'c');       // [ a, *c]
listAdd(L, 1, 'd');       // [ a, *d,  c]
listAdd(L, 3, 'e');       // [ a,  d,  c, *e]
listAdd(L, 2, 'f');       // [ a,  d, *f,  c,  e] 
listAdd(L, 3, 'f');       // [ a,  d,  f, *f,  c,  e]
```